# What's a software that I can use to design UI's with my team?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows

I want my team to be able to see my PSD and be able to edit it. Kinda like how code works on git-hub but for photoshop or UI design. I make a design, save it and my team member can get the latest version and it wont affect his or hers. I have seen wake.com but am on windows. Any suggestion

Comment: Does an online backup and sync program work?

Comment: I think you should try figma, it's like a google doc and sketch had a baby.

Comment: The title makes me think you want an alternative for your current application (Photoshop), such as Figma, but the description seems to be telling me that maybe you just want a file versioning/collaboration platform that works with Photoshop and perhaps other Adobe applications. Which one is it? Either one?

Comment: @Joonas either one honestly, as long as I can have a psd file and have my team be able to view or edit it

Comment: I think I will try to use Figma, I am so used to photoshop but I need to try other software. Plus Figma offers what I want, real time collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

We use invision. Paid subscription, but good tool to deliver designs to developers. It has a built in inspect tool that deliver the generated css to developers. Good tool to prototype with as well.

Comment: It's for Mac only though, I want something for Windows